# AWS iam:ListRolePolicies permissions error on all IAM service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a problem.
I'm using an AWS educate account, and when I try to follow tutorials (Lambda one in this case), I can't create/modify roles.

So, I go in the IAM dedicated page, and in this page, i can't create, edit or delete Users / roles / Groups etc..

When I create a role, this role is always as default and I can't modify it.

It's always about : iam:ListRolePolicies

Exemples :

Try to delete a Kinesis Role = User: arn:aws:sts::11111111:federated-user/myID is not authorized to perform: iam:ListRolePolicies on resource: role Kinesis-Data-Generator-Cog-UnauthenticatedUserRole-1T1HLD2QUMZ8T

Trying to modify the lambda role I just created = User: arn:aws:sts::11111111:federated-user/myID is not authorized to perform: iam:ListRolePolicies on resource: role lambda_dynamodb_execution

Is this a bug ? Can you help me ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: It doesn't *sound like* a bug... it sounds like you are simply lacking a permission that you need.

Comment: Oh.. I tried to contact AWS and I am waiting for an answer. It's quite akward, my account should look like any other educate account no? If I can't follow officials AWS educate tutorial there must be an error somewhere. If you had any informations I'll take it.

Answer (score 2):

So, I have the answer from AWS, that say :

> Hello,
>
> I apologize for the trouble you've had while attempting to use these
>   services. The IAM service is unavailable to Educate Starter Accounts
>   which is why you're running into these issues.
>
> If you don't believe the Starter account will meet your needs, we can
>   convert your AWS Educate benefits to the other option - credit for a
>   normal AWS account. In order to take advantage of this option, you
>   will need your own AWS account, which requires phone verification and
>   a valid credit card to activate. If you have not already done so, you
>   can visit https://aws.amazon.com to create a normal AWS account.
>
> Once you have an active AWS account, you can request conversion of
>   your AWS Educate benefits by logging in to your AWS account and
>   creating a case from the Support Center at the URL below.

So it seems *normal* that you can't do the educate tutorials with an educate account.. That quite strange..

Tutorial exemple :

> In the Create function window, configure the following:
>       
> - Name: Create-Thumbnail
>       
> - Runtime: Python 3.6
>       
> - Existing role: lambda-execution-role

All IAM roles have :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this will be usefull for someone else.